# What does the `forall a -> b` syntax mean?

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type, data-kinds, forall

In GHCi, the kind of `FUN` is displayed like this:

```
λ> :k FUN
FUN :: forall (n :: Multiplicity) -> * -> * -> *
```

At first, I thought this was a roundabout way of saying

```
FUN :: Multiplicity -> * -> * -> *
```

but it turns out Template Haskell has a separate constructor for this form: `ForallVisT`. I can't find any documentation on it, and I have no idea how to even begin experimenting with it in a meaningful way.

What does this syntax mean? How does `forall a -> b` differ from a "normal" `forall a. a -> b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`forall a -> _` is used when the result type depends on an explicit argument.

```
-- type NonDep :: Type -> Type; argument is explicit
data NonDep (x :: Type) :: Type
-- type ImpDep :: forall a. Maybe a -> Type; first argument is implicit and dependent
data ImpDep (x :: Maybe a) :: Type
-- so if you want an explicit and dependent argument...
-- type ExpDep :: forall (a :: Type) -> Maybe a -> Type
data ExpDep (a :: Type) (x :: Maybe a) :: Type
```

It is odd that `FUN`'s type has `forall (m :: Multiplicity) ->` and not `Multiplicity ->` as the following arguments (two implicit `RuntimeRep`s and two `TYPE`s) do not depend on it, but such is the weirdness that surrounds GHC primitives.